# List View check box not checked in non visible rows

Tags: android, android-widget

I am creating a list view with each row having custom layout. Each custom layout has a check-box. I have a check box, which on click has to click all the check boxes in the list view. I am able to click check boxes in visible rows but I am facing problem with non visible rows. I tried checking all in list adapter but its not working.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter;
    static List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
    public static int count = 0;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this,getModel());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        count = listView.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
        TextView label = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.label);
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v.getTag(R.id.check);
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), label.getText().toString()+" "+isCheckedOrNot(checkbox), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private String isCheckedOrNot(CheckBox checkbox) {
        if(checkbox.isChecked())
            return "is checked";
        else
            return "is not checked";
    }

    private List<Model> getModel() {
        list.add(new Model("Linux"));
        list.add(new Model("Windows7"));
        list.add(new Model("Suse"));
        list.add(new Model("Eclipse"));
        list.add(new Model("Ubuntu"));
        list.add(new Model("Solaris"));
        list.add(new Model("Android"));
        list.add(new Model("iPhone"));
        list.add(new Model("Java"));
        list.add(new Model(".Net"));
        list.add(new Model("PHP"));
        list.add(new Model("U1"));
        list.add(new Model("S1"));
        list.add(new Model("A1"));
        list.add(new Model("i1"));
        list.add(new Model("J1"));
        list.add(new Model(".N1"));
        list.add(new Model("PP1"));
        return list;
    }
}
```

MyAdapter .java

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context; 

    TextView text;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    boolean flag;

    public MyAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        final CheckBox c = (CheckBox) ((ViewGroup) parent.getParent()).getChildAt(0);


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

            text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);
            checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag(); 
                            list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                        }
                    });

        checkbox.setTag(position); 

        text.setText(list.get(position).getName());

        c.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {

                    RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) parent.getChildAt(i);

                    CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox) r.getChildAt(1);

                    if(check1 instanceof CheckBox){

                        check1.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        if(flag){

            list.get(position).setSelected(flag);

        }

        checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());   

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >
        </CheckBox>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/my_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="30sp" >
    </TextView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >
    </CheckBox>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @MSK..Can you explain in detail what you trying to do?

Comment: On clicking check box(check all button) in main layout ,I am trying to check all check boxes in list view..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list view only has as many children as you can see, therefore `getChildCount()` will only return what is visible.

You will need to have a field in your `Model` class that stores its `checked` state. So in your adapter's `getView` method you'll do something like

```
Model myModel = getItem(position);
checkBox.setChecked(myModel.isChecked());
```

`Select all` should loop through the list and mark all `Model` objects as checked and update the visible views in the list view. Next time you scroll the checkbox will read its checked state from the relevant model object, from inside `getView()`